# How to customize the Bootstrap navigation bar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-8

I'm trying to change the navigation bar so that it opens from left to right instead of up and down.

I want the navigation bar to shift to the right when the menu is open.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your #navbar-collapse id on your css file as this: I moved your menu at the right adding "right:0" because is positioned as "fixed" and move the border on the left.

```
#navbar-collapse {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
float: left;
z-index: 1031;
width: 220px;
height: 100% !important;
border-left: 1px solid #000000;
border-top: 0px;
background: #ffffff;}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not my question. I want to keep the navigation left and shift the button to open the mune to the right when it is open.